# Why I get null pointer when passing data with Bundle?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, bundle

I am using Location Fused Provider in my app and I want to send latitude and logitude in Firebase Upstream message from Main activity to the DashBoard Fragment where I have button for upstream message. I have posted similar question, but this is not duplicate. My question is why I get null pointer exception?

This is my method in `mainActivity` which should pass data:

```
private void updateUI(){
        if(null!=mCurrentLocation){

            String lat=String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
            String lot=String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("KEY_LAT", lat);
            bundle.putString("KEY_LNG", lot);
            DashboardFragment dashboardFragment=new DashboardFragment();
            dashboardFragment.setArguments(bundle);

}
```

And this is the part of `DashBoardFragment` where I should put latitude and longitude:

```
public void getObjectEvent(EventModel data){
    String longitude;
    longitude=getArguments().getString("KEY_LNG");
    Log.d("LONGITUDE", "Longitude is: " + longitude);
    Gson data_json = new Gson();
    String json=data_json.toJson(data);
    FirebaseMessaging fm=FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
    fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
            .setMessageId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .addData("action","message")
            .addData("data","{\"message\":\"Upstream Message\"}")
            .addData("object", json)
            .addData("longitude", longitude)
            .build());


}
```

And this is my null pointer:

```
08-08 14:17:12.755 13165-13165/com.telnet.asp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.telnet.asp.presentation.view.fragments.DashboardFragment.getObjectEvent(DashboardFragment.java:125)
at com.telnet.asp.presentation.view.adapters.DashboardGridAdapter.getDataObject(DashboardGridAdapter.java:145)
at com.telnet.asp.presentation.view.adapters.DashboardGridAdapter$3.onClick(DashboardGridAdapter.java:128)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: in which override function u calling getObjectEvent() ?

Comment: I am calling her in some another adapter which I called DashBoardGridAdapter

Comment: try calling Bundle bundle = getArguments(); and check whether it is null or not.

Comment: are u calling in onViewCreated() function ?

Comment: No no I am calling it in this getObjectEvent method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120426/discussion-between-darwin-and-atenica).